# Code is being skipped for elements that don't satisfy if statement

Tags: python

Doing a open.kattis.com problem, but the code in my for loop seems to have been coded wrong. My for loop is skipping elements.

I put in a variety of debugging, and tried switching the order around. However, it is apparent that the code is simply skipping elements where `x[i] > 0`.

```py
    y = int(input())
    x= input().split(' ')
    cont = True
    i = -1
    while i <len(x):
      i += 1
      print(int(x[i])-y)
      x[i] = int(x[i])-y
      print(x)
      if cont == True and x[i]<0:
        x.pop(i)
        continue
      else:
        cont = False
```

Using below Input:

```
y =   20
x = 18 35 6 80 15 21

-2
[-2, '35', '6', '80', '15', '21']

-14
['35', -14, '80', '15', '21']

-5
['35', '80', -5, '21']
```

Then it returns an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(int(x[i])-y)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Nevermind, problem was solved, I just needed to switch for a while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in range (0, len(x)):
  x[i] = int(x[i])-y
  x.pop(i)
```

This code can make `IndexError: list index out of range`
because, `x.pop()` reduce the `x` list, so `x[i]` can error

Comment: Kind of confused there, as my input went in order of 18,35, meaning (18-20)<0, removing it from the list, but the for loop should not have skipped 35, as (35-20)>0. However, the debugging output shows that the loop went directly to the third (now second) item of the list, leaving the second (now first) item still as a string.

Answer (score 0):

`pop` delete the element from the list, so the length is smaller than the original list. But you move the variable `i` for 0 to length of the original list, as a result `index out of range` error occurs.

Comment: Maybe you should make empty list and use method .append to add elements that meet your condition.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this simply, after you execute x.pop(),  decrease i by 1.

```
...
x.pop()
i -= 1
continue
...
```

After the first pass, `35` became the first number in your list, but your index becomes incremented to `2` on the second pass. So x[i] is x[2] = `-14`.

By the time it gets to the end of the list, your list has become too short for the given index resulting in an out of range error.

Answer (score 0):

You're checking x while you're popping off therefore list x is getting smaller while the loop index is larger.
Solution:

```
y = 20
x = "18 35 6 80 15 21".split(' ')
list_of_numbers = range(0, len(x))
[int(x[number]) for number in list_of_numbers if (int(x[number])-y)> 0]

[35, 80, 21]
```

Instead of popping off, do the opposite and leverage the power of list comprehensions!